# Printing Highcharts using the Adobe PDF print driver

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, highcharts

I'm trying to print a webpage that contains (among other things) a highcharts control. The printed page must contain all the other (non-highchart) elements as well, so the exporting module is not applicable. When printing the entire page using the Adobe PDF print driver it pops up with:

`An unknown error occurred while printing.`

Is what I am describing possible?

Thanks

Comment: it should be very well possible, did you try something like doPdf as the print driver? if you would add a link to the page it would be easy to simulate for other readers of this post, but my guess it should not be an issue at all as the print driver just should force everything to go to the printer.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a client request to be able to use Adobe. Sorry, system is not live yet, so don't have a link to provide. Will be deploying to a test server later this week, if I haven't figured it out by then I will update the post with the link.

Comment: Actually, here's a link that produces the same results for me: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-addpoint-append/ Press `Ctrl+P` in firefox and print using adobe PDF.

Comment: yeah I just printed this with free printer driver doPdf (http://www.dopdf.com) and it works just fine. You could also look at an online service to print it or save as PDF, like http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk or something

Comment: @user1914292 - Ok thanks for that. Unfortunately it is not helping me, because as I said: "Unfortunately it is a client request to be able to use Adobe". Thanks anyway, appreciated.